# can't use variable inside regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

So, I have a long sequence of Unicode characters that I want to match using regular expressions:

```
char_set = '\u0041-\u005A|\u00C0-\u00D6|\u00D8-\u00DE|\u0100|\u0102|\u0104|\u0106|\u0108|\u010A|\u010C|\u010E|\u0110|\u0112|\u0114|\u0116|\u0118|\u011A|\u011C|\u011E|\u0120|\u0122|\u0124|\u0126|\u0128|\u012A|\u012C|\u012E|\u0130|\u0132|\u0134|\u0136|\u0139|\u013B|\u013D|\u013F|\u0141|\u0143|\u0145|\u0147|\u014A|\u014C|\u014E|\u0150|\u0152|\u0154|\u0156|\u0158|\u015A|\u015C|\u015E|\u0160|\u0162|\u0164|\u0166|\u0168|\u016A|\u016C|\u016E|\u0170|\u0172|\u0174|\u0176|\u0178|\u0179|\u017B|\u017D'
```

(These are all the uppercase characters comprehended in the Unicode range 0-382. Most of them are accented. PEP8 discourages the use of non-ASCII characters in Python scripts, so I'm using the Unicode codes instead of the string literals.)

If I simply compile that long string directly, it works. For instance, this matches all the words that begin with one of those characters:

```
regex = re.compile(u'\A[\u0041-\u005A|\u00C0-\u00D6|\u00D8-\u00DE|\u0100|\u0102|\u0104|\u0106|\u0108|\u010A|\u010C|\u010E|\u0110|\u0112|\u0114|\u0116|\u0118|\u011A|\u011C|\u011E|\u0120|\u0122|\u0124|\u0126|\u0128|\u012A|\u012C|\u012E|\u0130|\u0132|\u0134|\u0136|\u0139|\u013B|\u013D|\u013F|\u0141|\u0143|\u0145|\u0147|\u014A|\u014C|\u014E|\u0150|\u0152|\u0154|\u0156|\u0158|\u015A|\u015C|\u015E|\u0160|\u0162|\u0164|\u0166|\u0168|\u016A|\u016C|\u016E|\u0170|\u0172|\u0174|\u0176|\u0178|\u0179|\u017B|\u017D]')
```

But I want to re-use that same sequence of characters in several other regular expressions. I could simply copy and paste it every time, but that's ugly. So based on previous answers to similar questions I've tried this:

`regex = re.compile(u'\A[%s]' % char_set)`

No good. Somehow the above expression seems to match ANY character, not just the ones hardcoded under the variable 'char_set'.

I've also tried this:

`regex = re.compile(u'\A[' + char_set + ']')`

And this:

`regex = re.compile(u'\A[' + re.escape(char_set) + ']')`

And this too:

`regex = re.compile(u'\A[{ }]'.format(char_set))`

None of which works as expected.

Any thoughts? What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using Python 2.7 and Mac OS X 10.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a pattern with a set of characters in square brackets, you don't want to put any vertical bar (`|`) characters in the set. Instead, just string the characters together and it should work. Here's a session where I tried out your characters with no problems after stripping the `|` chars:

```
>>> import re
>>> char_set = u'\u0041-\u005A|\u00C0-\u00D6|\u00D8-\u00DE|\u0100|\u0102|\u0104|\u0106|\u0108|\u010A|\u010C|\u010E|\u0110|\u0112|\u0114|\u0116|\u0118|\u011A|\u011C|\u011E|\u0120|\u0122|\u0124|\u0126|\u0128|\u012A|\u012C|\u012E|\u0130|\u0132|\u0134|\u0136|\u0139|\u013B|\u013D|\u013F|\u0141|\u0143|\u0145|\u0147|\u014A|\u014C|\u014E|\u0150|\u0152|\u0154|\u0156|\u0158|\u015A|\u015C|\u015E|\u0160|\u0162|\u0164|\u0166|\u0168|\u016A|\u016C|\u016E|\u0170|\u0172|\u0174|\u0176|\u0178|\u0179|\u017B|\u017D'
>>> fixed_char_set = char_set.replace("|", "")   # remove the unneeded vertical bars
>>> pattern = ur"\A[{}]".format(fixed_char_set)  # create a pattern string
>>> regex = re.compile(pattern) # compile the pattern into a regex object
>>> print regex.match("%foo")   # "%" is not in the character set, so match returns None
None
```

edit: Actually, it seems like there must be some other issue going on, since I don't match `"%foo"` even if I use your original char_set without stripping out anything. Please give examples of text that is matching when it shouldn't!

Comment: I just found the issue: I didn't include the 'u' before the string. I noticed that you did, so I tried it to see if it made any difference. And it did: now the code works. Many thanks!